# Code compiles in Visual Studio 2010 but shouldn't compile at all

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The following source code compiles correctly with Visual Studio 2010:

```
namespace NS
   {
   class X
      {
      };   
   X Y(X str);
   } 

void myFun()
   {
   NS::X x;
   Y(x);
   }
```

(this is reduced code where all my own class and function names have been replaced by X, Y, ...)

I would expect that the line `Y(x)` would fail to compile, since it should be `NS::Y(x)`.

This source code is compiled with the following command

```
cl /c file.cpp
```

There are no other files included here, no other command line options.

Why does this file compile?
Bug in VS2010?  Or something that I (and my 3 other colleagues) overlooked?

Comment: tried this with g++ and got `undefined reference to NS::Y(NS::X)'` - so maybe it might be a bug in VS..

Comment: @WeaselFox: completely unrelated. Your error is a *linker error* because `NS::Y` is not defined. It is typical, and would probably be defined in another file on a complete setup.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - yeah, I realize this, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are experiencing is due to `ADL` ([Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)).

There is nothing wrong with your snippet (besides the fact that the linker will probably complain about `NS::Y` isn't defined), but it should compile - VS2012 is handling the snippet as it should.

The compiler will find `NS::Y` due to the fact that the type of parameter `x` (`NS::X`) is in the appropriate scope.

---

> **3.4.2** *Argument-dependent name lookup* [**basic.lookup.argdep**]
>
> 1. When an unqualified name is used as the postfix-expression in a
>      function call (5.2.2), other namespaces not considered during the
>      usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched, and in those
>      namespaces, namespace-scope friend function declarations (11.4) not
>      otherwise visible may be found.
>
>    These modifications to the search depend on the types of the
>      arguments (and for template template arguments, the namespace of the
>      template argument).
> 2. For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more
>      associated classes to be considered.
>
>    The sets of namespaces and
>      classes is determined entirely by the types of the function arguments
>      (and the namespace of any template template argument).

Comment: You're right, I just also found it on Wikipedia.  Tricky.  I didn't expect this to work.

Comment: So is it a bug in MSVS or gcc?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There is no bug, the snippet compiles. The linker just can't find the definition of `NS::Y`. There are several steps when building an executable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Neither. MSVC is not erroring as it is only compiling to an object file. The g++ error is coming from the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I though it compiled with MSVS and not gcc. Totally misunderstood the question. The linker error was obvious, not what I had doubts about.

Answer (score 3):

It is valid C++ code. It is compiled since [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) applies here.