# Why some Boost functions don't need prefixing with namespace

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider this code (or the [live example](https://ideone.com/dY6Gru)):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

using std::cout;

int main() {
  boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> g;

  add_edge(0, 1, g);
  add_edge(1, 2, g);

  for(auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
    cout << v << " has " << degree(v, g) << " neighbor(s): ";
    for(auto w : make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(v, g))) cout << w << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why do functions `add_edge`, `make_iterator_range`, `vertices`, `degree` and `adjacent_vertices` that come from the Boost library work without the `boost::` namespace prefix?

What is most puzzling to me is that depending on the situation, the prefix is actually needed sometimes. [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/z6jccg), when using a different graph structure results in a compilation error that can be fixed by prefixing `boost::make_iterator_range`.

I looked a bit around the [BGL documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html), but didn't find anything regarding this issue. Is it my fault or are some BGL headers polluting the global namespace? Is this by design or is this a bug?

Comment: Argument-dependent lookup (ADL), a.k.a. Koenig lookup (after Andrew Koenig).

Comment: I'm reopening this question because someone may want to explain in detail, why the linked code doesn't compile

Comment: Despite there being other questions on ADL (which are hard enough to find, especially without searching the term ADL), this is a very well-asked question. The main thing that can be improved is that this happens with all namespaces rather than Boost, but I can look past it not clicking to try that.

Comment: Ah, according to the documentation, `vertices` returns a `std::pair`, so that `make_iterator_range` does indeed need the qualification. The others you have without the qualification all compile, though. It looks like ideone's version of GCC has a bug there. 5.2 doesn't compile it.

Comment: @chris I think that if type template arguments of this `std::pair` come from the boost's namesapce, then ADL still takes place

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, Considering GCC 5.2 and Clang 3.7 (both on Coliru) don't compile it, I'll bet on that side, especially if GCC used to compile it and no longer does.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, [I stand corrected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f75fc7cd54fe126b). I have a feeling there might be more to `vertices` than the documentation says in that regard, or maybe `vertex_iterator` (the argument types to the `std::pair`) is sometimes a type in Boost and sometimes not.

Comment: Funny thing `boost::graph_traits<decltype(g)>::vertex_iterator` returns an iterator from the `std` namespace for the non-compiling code, while it returns a range iterator from the `boost` namespace for the compiling one. So this is clearly an ADL issue, related to an internal representation of different graph types

Comment: In any case, @OP, [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819782/code-compiles-in-visual-studio-2010-but-shouldnt-compile-at-all) of which I earlier closed this as a duplicate. It's still helpful for the first part of the question. The more interesting answer here would be for the second link not compiling. And now I'm more curious why the first compiles with one fairly recent version of GCC, but not another. I'm kind of leaning away from the idea of a compiler bug, instead thinking that Boost might be doing some compiler-dependent tricks behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not related to `boost` but to any `namespace`.

With [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL), namespaces from the argument are added to the search of overloads.

So for example:

```
add_edge(0, 1, g);
```

`g` is from namespace `boost`, so we look for `add_edge` also in namespace `boost`.

Comment: I don't think this really answers why the other code example linked by the OP does not compile.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: In failing code, `vertices(g)` returns a `std::pair<std::list<void*>::iterator, std::std::list<void*>::iterator>` (nothing from `boost`), so `make_iterator_range` only search in global and `std` namespace.